# Determining the presence of a notch on a device in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile-application, device-detection

I'm developing a Flutter application and I need to detect whether the device running the app has a notch or not. Is there a reliable way to determine the presence of a notch programmatically in Flutter?

I have already explored the Flutter's MediaQuery class, but I couldn't find any direct property or method that provides information about the notch. Is there any other approach or package available that can help me achieve this?

Any guidance or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you mention why you are looking for that ? I mean if there is any ui issue because of notch then ```SafeAreaView``` is there

Comment: Yeaah Safe Area is the option, but in my scenario i want to display poster on full screen and now i have to add arrow button for some reason below that notch